# Google unable to crawl my website

Tags: google-search-console

Recently i have a crawl error appear in my google search console :

> Google couldn't crawl your site because we were unable to access your
>   site's robots.txt file

my robots.txt content :

```
User-agent: * 
Disallow: /wp-admin/  
Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
Sitemap: http://www.name.com/sitemap.xml
```

when i try FETCH AS GOOGLE it say :

> Temporarily unreachable

Comment: It's also possibility google has add your domain in their spam list.

Answer (score 0):

Common causes for this error is blocked google ip address by hosting company. You can contact your hosting company and find out whether this is so.